# Java Servlet 3.0 File Upload - Removing TMP Files

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm using the Java Servlet 3.0 to upload files, using the `@MultipartConfig` annotation and `request.getParts()` to obtain the files.

When a file is uploaded, a TMP file is created in the Web Application work directory (`tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/webappname`). For example:

```
upload_7c59101b_9f97_4e3f_9fa5_e484056d26fa_00000209.tmp
```

The application copies the file to another directory on the server - I'm doing this using the `part.write()` method but it's also working by obtaining the input stream and writing the bytes. Either way works fine.

I need to remove the TMP files after the upload, but I'm having trouble doing so. The `part.delete()` method doesn't do anything. I've also tried accessing the files in the directory using `javax.servlet.context.tempdir` and iterating over them to delete, but when calling a delete method, it always returns false. Using the `Files.delete(path)` method from `Files.nio` returns an exception which claims the file is in use by another program (i.e. locked) and therefore cannot be deleted. The server is running Windows Server 2012 R2.

Does anyone have any other solutions to remove these TMP files? It's worth pointing out that I've tried using a `HttpRequestListener` too, but still cannot delete the files.

Many thanks

Comment: You need to close all streams to files you use.

Comment: Yes, all streams are being closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should (must!) not manipulate the files directly, you should use the `getInputStream()` method of the particular `Part` to get the content of the uploaded file. The servlet container (Tomcat in your case) will - or at least should - take care of the temporary files.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've used `part.getInputStream()` rather than `part.write()`. Closing the input stream after writing it to a file seems to have resolved the issue and the temporary files are being removed.

Comment: This is not correct. The `Part` interface provides a `write()` method that allows a caller to move the underlying file to another location.

Answer (score 0):

Along with `InputStream.close()`, use `Part.delete()` to remove the stored temporary file under *work* directory. Please refer the [javadoc: Part.delete()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html#delete()).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jozef Chocholacek answer, simple solution CLOSE the input.
We were using MultiPart messages with files upload. 
Since we were not closing the inputStream the files were stored there for a loooong time. They were deleted only on server restart.

After slightly changing the implementation with always closing the input part at the end.

> Use try-> catch-> finally and put closing in **finally** part which will be
>   called always even when the call of method fails.

The server is not storing .tmp files anymore.