# GraphQL Error: Expected a user-defined GraphQL scalar type with name 'FileUpload' but found none

Tags: java, graphql

for several days I have been trying to implement the upload file in Java-GraphQL. I found this topic: [How to upload files with graphql-java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57372259/how-to-upload-files-with-graphql-java#autocomment104062852)  I implemented second solutions.

```
public class FileUpload {
    private String contentType;
    private byte[] content;

    public FileUpload(String contentType, byte[] content) {
        this.contentType = contentType;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    public byte[] getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

```
public class MyScalars {
    public static final GraphQLScalarType FileUpload = new GraphQLScalarType(
        "FileUpload",
        "A file part in a multipart request",
        new Coercing<FileUpload, Void>() {

            @Override
            public Void serialize(Object dataFetcherResult) {
                throw new CoercingSerializeException("Upload is an input-only type");
            }

            @Override
            public FileUpload parseValue(Object input) {
                if (input instanceof Part) {
                    Part part = (Part) input;
                    try {
                        String contentType = part.getContentType();
                        byte[] content = new byte[part.getInputStream().available()];
                        part.delete();
                        return new FileUpload(contentType, content);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new CoercingParseValueException("Couldn't read content of the uploaded file");
                    }
                } else if (null == input) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    throw new CoercingParseValueException(
                            "Expected type " + Part.class.getName() + " but was " + input.getClass().getName());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public FileUpload parseLiteral(Object input) {
                throw new CoercingParseLiteralException(
                        "Must use variables to specify Upload values");
            }
    });
}
```

```
public class FileUploadResolver implements GraphQLMutationResolver {

    public Boolean uploadFile(FileUpload fileUpload) {

        String fileContentType = fileUpload.getContentType();
        byte[] fileContent = fileUpload.getContent();

        // Do something in order to persist the file :)


        return true;
    }
}
```

```
scalar FileUpload

type Mutation {
    uploadFile(fileUpload: FileUpload): Boolean
}
```

I get this error during compilation:

Caused by: com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaClassScannerError: Expected a user-defined GraphQL scalar type with name 'FileUpload' but found none!

Comment: @Andreas Larson

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered it via         RuntimeWiring?

Take a look here: [Custom Scalar in Graphql-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46034801/custom-scalar-in-graphql-java)

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend **GraphQLScalarType** in your MyScalars class